# Store hash-like id in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, normalization

I have a hash-like id from foursquare api. It is not numeric

example:

> 'fadf122ddadfsfdaafd'

, like ObjectId in mongo db. I wan't to cache data from foursquare, and id's important. How should I deal with this long ids. I think it will slow down my performance if I will make it primary key. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a varchar, or char of the appropriate length if the latter is the same everywhere.

If you want to cache the data it's a good candidate for a primary key. If you really prefer to use a serial as the primary key, add a unique key on it. (Slower writes, since you then have two unique checks to do.)

Aside: if it's really a cache that you don't actually need to persist, it could also belong in memcached.

Comment: I am using node js for my app, I try to do it with radis, but it is so painful, now I afraid of this type of storage.